# Matrox G450 on a motherboard with onboard Graphic Card not working

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

I have a computer with a [BIOSTAR 865GV Micro 478 Motherboard](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/content.php?S_ID=234). It has a Intel Graphic Card onboard, to get a Dual Head Display I but in a Matrox G450 Dual Head DVI Graphic Card.

Now every time I try to disable the Intel Onboard Graphic Card in Windows, the screen just stays black, although the Graphic Card shows up as installed, it's not used by Windows. Disabeling the onboard Card in the BIOS is not possible.

I tried to disable the Graphic Card in Hardware Manager, I tried to uninstall the Driver for the Graphic Card.

The Graphic Card is only used when I boot in Safe Mode or in VGA Mode.

Comment: Why can't you disable in BIOS?  If you can't, every time Windows boots it will re-detect the onboard graphics and reinstall the drivers for it if you have uninstalled them.

Comment: Because the Motherboard doesn't support it, also according to manual. I tried to disable in the Device Manager, which led to a black screen on all display ports.

Comment: We now changed the Graphic Card, a different make allowed us the things we needed. No solution found.